# Binary relation $ R \subseteq S \times S $ that contains every element of $ S $

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Let $ R \subseteq S \times S $ be a binary relation. Is there some terminology that states that $ R $ contains every element of $ S $ (either in the first or second position of a tuple in $ R $)? In other words, does the property $$ s \in S \implies \exists t \in S : (s,t) \in R \text{ or } (t,s) \in R $$
have a special name?

Comment: We may say that $R$ is *total* on $S$ or *left-total* if $S= \text {Dom}(R)$

Comment: Note that in order to fulfill the condition above, the relation does not have to be left-total nor right-total.